# Display Posts in Custom Post Types Timber

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I am working on a Timber/Twig template and have created a Custom Post Type with a Taxonomy specific to that Post Type.

```
$tour_labels = array(
    'name'                  => _x( 'Tours', 'Post Type General Name', 'standrews' ),
    'singular_name'         => _x( 'Tour', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'standrews' ),
    'menu_name'             => __( 'Tours', 'standrews' )
);
$tour_rewrite = array(
    'slug'                  => 'tours-excursion',
    'with_front'            => false,
    'pages'                 => true,
    'feeds'                 => true,
);
$tour_args = array(
    'label'                 => __( 'Tours', 'standrews' ),
    'description'           => __( 'Tour Description', 'standrews' ),
    'labels'                => $tour_labels,
    'supports'              => array( 'title', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail', 'trackbacks', 'revisions', ),
    'taxonomies'            => array( 'post_tag', 'tour_category' ),
    'hierarchical'          => false,
    'has_archive'           => 'tours-excursions',
    'exclude_from_search'   => false,
    'publicly_queryable'    => true,
    'rewrite'               => $tour_rewrite,
    'capability_type'       => 'post',
);
register_post_type( 'tours', $tour_args );
```

Taxomony to create Tour Categories

```
$tours_labels = array(
    'name'                       => _x( 'Categories Tours', 'Taxonomy General Name', 'standrews' ),
    'singular_name'              => _x( 'Category Tour', 'Taxonomy Singular Name', 'standrews' ),
    'menu_name'                  => __( 'Categories Tours', 'standrews' )
);
$tours_rewrite = array(
    'slug'                       => 'tours-excursions',
    'with_front'                 => true,
);
$tours_args = array(
    'labels'                     => $tours_labels,
    'hierarchical'               => true,
    'public'                     => true,
    'show_ui'                    => true,
    'show_admin_column'          => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
    'show_tagcloud'              => true,
    'rewrite'                    => $tours_rewrite,
);
register_taxonomy( 'tour_category', array( 'tours' ), $tours_args );
```

Inside the tour_category Taxonomy, I have 3 Categories (Sightseeing Tours, Golf Breaks & Walking Tours)

I have created an archive-tours.php file to call the archive-tours.twig

```
$templates = array('archives/archive-tours.twig');
$context = Timber::get_context();
$context['title'] = 'Archive Tours';
if (is_category()){
    $context['title'] = single_cat_title('', false);
    array_unshift($templates, 'archives/archive-'.get_query_var('cat').'.twig');
} else if (is_post_type_archive()){
    $context['title'] = post_type_archive_title('', false);
    array_unshift($templates, 'archives/archive-'.get_post_type().'.twig');
}
$context['posts'] = Timber::get_posts();
Timber::render($templates, $context);
```

The Tours Twig template

```
{% block content %}
  <p>Archive (archive-tours.twig)</p>
  {% for post in posts %}
    {% include ['teases/_tease-'~post.post_type~'.twig', 'teases/tease.twig'] %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Ideally what I am aiming for is a way to call a separate tease template for the 3 categories, however unsure about how to achieve this.

Answer (score 3):

It's a late reply and I suspect you might have it figured out already, but if someone is looking for the same info, here's an example.

```
{% for post in posts %}
    {% set post_terms  = post.terms('tour_category') %}
    {% if function( 'has_term', 'Sightseeing Tours', 'tour_category' ) %}
        {% set teaser = 'sightseeing' %}
    {% elseif function( 'has_term', 'Golf Breaks', 'tour_category' ) %}
        {% set teaser = 'golfbreak' %}
    {% elseif function( 'has_term', 'Walking Tours', 'tour_category' ) %}
        {% set teaser = 'wlkingtour' %}
    {% endif %}
    {% include ['teases/_tease-'~teaser~'.twig', 'teases/tease.twig'] %}
{% endfor %}
```